# Drawing a thick line through rows of a table to separate first column from second column

Tags: tables

I have code for a table to be drawn. It is almost what I want. I am requesting three modifications to be made to it.

I would like vertical lines, forming the left and right edges of the table, to be drawn. These lines together with the horizontal line above the title and the horizontal line after the last row of the table should make a rectangle.

There are two vertical lines separating the three columns. I would like the vertical line separating the first column from the other two columns to be either 1.5 times thicker than the vertical line separating the second and third column and the vertical lines forming the left and right edges of the table. (In the code provided, two parallel lines drawn close to each other separate the first and second columns.)

The data - certain percentages - should be horizontally centered in their rows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l||r|r}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{---Title is Lengthy --- Here is First Line}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Here is Second Line}} \\ \hline\hline
\textbf{Class}&\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5in}|}{\textbf{Percent Present in Habitat A}}&\multicolumn{1}{C{1.75in}}{\textbf{Percent Present in Habitat B}}\\\hline

\textbf{Mammals}                        &                   &               \\
\hspace*{1em}Dog                        &   20\%            &   5\%         \\
\hspace*{1em}Cow                        &   10\%            &   7\%         \\ \hline
\textbf{Bird}                           &                   &               \\
\hspace*{1em}Peacock                    &   15\%            &   25\%        \\ \hline
\hspace*{1em}Turkey                     &   25\%            &   40\%        \\ \hline
\textbf{Animals}                        &   \textbf{3\%}    &   \textbf{5\%}    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the thicker vertical line, you have the `boldline` package which does exactly what you want, with syntax `V{num}` in the table preamble to obtain a vertical rule with thickness num times \arrayrulewidth.

Other than that, I simplified a bit your code, and propose two variants,– the second with the `\thead` command, from `makecell`, which allows for line breaks within standard columns and a common formatting. Furthermore, the content of `\thead` is centred by default, both vertically and horizontally.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline}\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont} {\normalsize\bfseries}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|lV{1.5}c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{---Title is Lengthy --- Here is First Line}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Here is Second Line}} \\ \hline\hline
\textbf{Class}&\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5in}|}{\textbf{Percent Present in Habitat A}}&\multicolumn{1}{C{1.75in}|}{\textbf{Percent Present in Habitat B}}\\\hline

\textbf{Mammals} & & \\
\quad Dog & 20\% & 5\% \\
\quad Cow & 10\% & 7\% \\ \hline
\textbf{Bird} & & \\
\quad Peacock & 15\% & 25\% \\ \hline
\quad Turkey & 25\% & 40\% \\ \hline
\textbf{Animals} & \textbf{3\%} & \textbf{5\%} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vskip 1cm

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|lV{1.5}c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{---Title is Lengthy --- Here is First Line\\ Here is Second Line}} \\ \hline\hline
\textbf{Class}&\thead{Percent Present in \\ Habitat A} &\thead{Percent Present in \\ Habitat B}\\\hline

\textbf{Mammals} & & \\
\quad Dog & 20\% & 5\% \\
\quad Cow & 10\% & 7\% \\ \hline
\textbf{Bird} & & \\
\quad Peacock & 15\% & 25\% \\ \hline
\quad Turkey & 25\% & 40\% \\ \hline
\textbf{Animals} & \textbf{3\%} & \textbf{5\%} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have an unboxed title, and a bigger vertical spacing between the title and the first horizontal line, you can use this code:

```
    \begin{tabular}{|lV{1.5}c|c|}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{---Title is Lengthy --- Here is First Line\\ Here is Second Line}} \\
    \noalign{\vspace{2ex}}\hline
    \textbf{Class}&\thead{Percent Present in \\ Habitat A} & \thead{Percent Present in \\ Habitat B}\\ \hline
    \textbf{Mammals} & & \\
    \quad Dog & 20\% & 5\% \\
    \quad Cow & 10\% & 7\% \\ \hline
    \textbf{Bird} & & \\
    \quad Peacock & 15\% & 25\% \\ \hline
    \quad Turkey & 25\% & 40\% \\ \hline
    \textbf{Animals} & \textbf{3\%} & \textbf{5\%} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: That is the display that I want.

Comment: Which one, out of curiosity?

Comment: You just have to remove the first two `\hline`s and use `\multicolumn{3}{c}` (instead of `{|c|}`).

Comment: You say that using the `\thead` command centers the data vertically. Except for a difference in the widths of the tables, they look the same.

Comment: Yes,  the width is adapted to the content. In the solution with `\thead` you don't have to predefine the width of the columns: it corresponds to the natural width, and may vary with the insertion points of the line breaks.

Comment: If I do not surround the title with a box, I would like a bit more vertical space between the title and the table. What would you suggest?

Comment: Wait a moment, I'll post an  example.

Comment: I've posted an example. Is it more or less like you want?

Comment: Yes. Thanks!  What is `\noalign` in this code? In what `\usepackage` is it implemented?

Comment: It is used to insert things between two rows, which do not have to be aligned within a column.